# Tomboy sync; local folder resets to wrong path

Tags: sync, tomboy

Because Tomboy synchronization with Ubuntu One is [being dropped soon](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/ubuntu-one-announce-tomboy-note-sync-to-stop-working-late-february), I want to sync my notes using Dropbox. I set the preferences so that Tomboy syncs with my local Dropbox folder: /home/duxk/Documents/Dropbox/Tomboy

When I save these settings, however, the folder path is changed automatically to /home/duxk and my Tomboy notes are synced to that folder instead.

Any idea how to fix this? Alternatively, where can I find Tomboy's configuration file that indicates which folder it syncs to?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has been driving me nuts! Glad to say I've found something that works.

It looks like there is a bug in the "Other" file locations dialogue. If you try to set it using that it messes up and defaults to your home directory. Not useful.

I use Ubuntu One for my synching, so I'll put things in those terms. It'll work just as well for Dropbox.

In your file manager, go to the Ubuntu One directory, create your new directory, I used the imaginative name "Tomboy Notes".

Now bookmark the location so it appears in the menu on the left.

Go into Tomboy.

Clear any sync settings you have, click on "Folder Path" and click on the "Tomboy Notes" (if that's what you called it) directory.

Click save.

Click yes to synch.

Job done.

Edit: Optional clean-up: Now the link to the right directory has been established, you don't need the bookmark any more, it's safe to delete.